# Best algorithm to find a region of the same values

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I would like to return a list of the pixels that belongs to the same region, after clicking on one of them. The input would be the chosen pixel (seed) and the output would be a list of all pixels that have the same value and belongs to the same region (are not separatet by any pixel of different value).

My idea was to create an auxiliary list of seeds and check the neighbours of each of them. If the value of the neighbour is the same as of the seed, it is appended to the region list. My python implementation is below:

```
def region_growing(x, y):

    value = image[x,y]
    region = [(x,y),]
    seeds = [(x,y),]

    while seeds:
        seed = seeds.pop()
        x = seed[0]
        y = seed[1]
        for i in range(x-1, x+2):
            for j in range(y-1, y+2):
                if image[i,j] == value:
                    point = (i,j,z)
                    if point not in region:
                        seeds.append(point)
                        region.append(point)
    return region
```

It works, but is very slow for bigger regions. What algorithm would you suggest?

Comment: `point not in region` is very slow.   It will be much faster if you use a `set` of visited points instead of a list.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the instruction `if point not in region` whose execution time will increase with the size of the region. The complexity is thus quadratic.

Another problem is that you visit the same pixels multiple times at the boundary of the region since you only keep track of pixels in the region.

You can avoid this by using a dictionary of visited pixels with the point as key.

```py
def region_growing(x, y):
    value = image[x,y]
    region = [(x,y),]
    seeds = [(x,y),]
    visited = {(x,y):true}

    while seeds:
        seed = seeds.pop()
        x = seed[0]
        y = seed[1]
        for i in range(x-1, x+2):
            for j in range(y-1, y+2):
                point = (i,j)
                if point in visited:
                    continue
                visited[point] = true
                if image[i,j] == value:
                    region.append(point)
                    seeds.append(point)
    return region
```

Another method is to use a matrix of booleans instead of the dictionary. This is faster but requires more memory space.

Comment: Thanks. I would only suggest to use a set instead of a dictionary. I think it is a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to use any region-fill/paint algorithm and patch it not to paint but to track pixels of the same region. The Smith's algorithm  is known to be fast and efficient, see [Tint Fill Algorithm](http://alvyray.com/Papers/CG/tintfi79.pdf).

Note that it is inefficient to store all pixels, but as the algorithm suggest horizontal segments are sufficient (thus only two pixels par segment).